# What numeric representational scheme is being used to represent the colors in this .ini file?

Tags: colors, encoding, user-interface, color-theme, delphi

I am modifying an .ini settings file to change the colors of a Windows application.

The existing colors are all represented by decimal integers, ranging from -16777201 to 536870911.

Obviously, those values aren't simply RGB or HSL. I'm almost certain that they are hexadecimal 16-bit RGB words converted to decimal, but the negative values have me a little confused. Also, the RGB seems to likely be inverted as BGR.

What numeric scheme is likely being used to represent the colors?

The application is closed-source, and I'm not sure which programming language was used to create it. I'm thinking it's likely Delphi.

(By the way, a link to any web-based tool to convert such values to/from RGB is also welcome!)

Comment: *"hexadecimal 16-bit ... values"* --  That's an oxymoron expression.  Bits are for binary representation, and hexadecimal digits are for hexadecimal representation.  Those values you use as examples are too large for 16-bit (binary) representation.  It's more like 32 bits (or 8 hex digits).  *"the negative values have me a little confused"* -- Ever hear of "two's complement" for representing negative integer values?

Comment: Don't know the answer offhand, but sounds like fun to investigate. The range you provided? Do you know if thats the range of allowed values or just the maximum variance in teh values you've seen defined? Are the colors assigned to GUI elements where you know the value associated with the color displayed? A capture & sample of the color in an image editor would give you an 
 RGB value that would give clues to decoding. PowerShell should be all you need for the endoding side.

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, it's been an enjoyable challenge figuring it out so far. I suspect the values are not the complete range, but just the maximum variance in the values currently in the .ini file.  There are no known values to compare, but converting the decimal values to hex, and then inverting RGB to BGR is giving me ranges I expect. The negative decimal integers and those requiring more than 6 hex digits to represent are still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: The "negative values" are simply a function of the default interpetation of a Dword value as a signed integer. But the code using it most likely dealing with a "set" of four bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Converting to hex with **PowerShell**

This code will define a function called **Parse-Color**. Should make the detective work easy:

```
Function Parse-Color {
   param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory,
        ValueFromPipeline)]
     [Int32[]]
     $IniColor
   )
   Process { FOrEach ( $Color in $IniColor ) {
      $Hex   = '{0:X8}' -f $Color
      [PSCustomObject]@{
         Int32 = $_
         Hex   = '0x{0}' -f $Hex
         Byte0 = -join $Hex[6,7] # Change these labels
         Byte1 = -join $Hex[3,5] # to the channel
         Byte2 = -join $Hex[2,3] # namee as they're
         Byte3 = -join $Hex[0,1] # determined.
      }
   }
}}
If ( -not ( Get-Alias pc -ea silent )) {
   Set-Alias pc Parse-Color
}
```

Then invoked via the pipeline:

```
-16777201, 536870911 | Parse-Color | Format-Table
```

Which yields:

```
PS C:\> -16777201, 536870911 | Parse-Color | Format-Table

    Int32 Hex        Byte0 Byte1 Byte2 Byte3
    ----- ---        ----- ----- ----- -----
-16777201 0xFF00000F 0F    00    00    FF
536870911 0x1FFFFFFF FF    FF    FF    1F


PS C:\>
```

Most likely suspect: RGB color with Alpha channel

Less likely: CMYK

### Edit: Adding Parse-Color to the profile.

**Option 1)** Down & difty: Add code directly to profile:

1. Copy the above Function code to the Clipboard.
2. Type: `Get-Clipboard | Add-Content $PROFILE`
   or
   `gcb | ac $PROFILE`
3. Launch a new PS session to verify the function has been added.

**Option 2)** Save as .ps1 file & dot-source from profile.

4. Copy the code to the Clipboard
5. Type: `$code = gcb`
6. Type: `$path = 'c:\Some\path\filename.ps1'
7. Type: `sc $path $code`
8. Type: `ac $Profile ". $Path"`

Comment: Thanks Keith! My memory of PowerShell details are a bit faded at the moment. What steps do I take with your function to make it available at the PS prompt?

Comment: Make it part of your profile. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Great. Thanks. For each option 1 and 2, how do you remove it from the profile?

Comment: manual edit: `notepad $PROFILE`